# one-hot encode : list of column_values has to encode

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a column_names in the list and I want to One-Hot encode values from the columns in list . I want to encode categorical variable from the dataset.I tried few procedures but it throws me an error

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
#training_set_ed is where my .csv file is stored
edited_training_set = 'edited_dataset/test_set.csv'
trainig_set_ed = pd.read_csv(edited_training_set)

column_header = ['cat_var_1','cat_var_2','cat_var_3','cat_var_4','cat_var_5','cat_var_6',
        'cat_var_7','cat_var_8','cat_var_9','cat_var_10','cat_var_11','cat_var_12','cat_var_13',
        'cat_var_14','cat_var_15','cat_var_16','cat_var_17','cat_var_18']
clfs = {c:LabelEncoder() for c in column_header}

for col,clf in clfs.items():

      trainig_set_ed[col] = clfs[col].fit_transform(trainig_set_ed[col])

trainig_set_ed.to_csv('edited_dataset/train_set_encode.csv',sep='\t',encoding='utf-8')
```

error it throws

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "preprocessing.py", line 83, in 
>       trainig_set_ed[col] = clfs[col].fit_transform(trainig_set_ed[col])
>     File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2139, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_column(key)
>     File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
>       return self._get_item_cache(key)
>     File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
>       values = self._data.get(item)
>     File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3838, in get
>       loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>     File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2524, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   KeyError: 'cat_var_6'

Thanks !

Comment: What's the error? Have you looked into [pandas.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

Comment: do you want to encode your features independently or not? Please provide a small reproducible data set and your desired data set - this will help to understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: i want to encode features independently..

Comment: Looks like `training_set_ed` is actually a `str`, not a pandas object. Can you share the code you’re using to create it?

Comment: okay i'll update the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo:

Source DF:

```
In [93]: df
Out[93]:
     a    b    c
0  aaa  xxx  ddd
1  bbb  zzz  bbb
2  ccc  aaa  aaa
```

Solution:

```
In [94]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    ...:
    ...: cols = ['a','b','c']
    ...: clfs = {c:LabelEncoder() for c in cols}
    ...:

In [95]: for col, clf in clfs.items():
    ...:     df[col] = clfs[col].fit_transform(df[col])
    ...:

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  1  2  1
2  2  0  0
```

Inverse transformation:

```
In [97]: clfs['a'].inverse_transform(df['a'])
Out[97]: array(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], dtype=object)

In [98]: clfs['b'].inverse_transform(df['b'])
Out[98]: array(['xxx', 'zzz', 'aaa'], dtype=object)

In [99]: clfs['c'].inverse_transform(df['c'])
Out[99]: array(['ddd', 'bbb', 'aaa'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: @Madhi, please open a new question and post there all corresponding details - your code, full error traceback and a dictionary producing that error

Comment: okay i'll update this question...I have very less reputation so i can't able to post many number of questions  .. :)